# Yii: Using getPut and getPost methods in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with title and done and id fields,
Now the problem is that when I click on the add button, the data is not stored in the table and the data is not displayed, if I save my data directly the rest of the code works but add button does not work, what is the problem?

I have the following code

**controller**

```
<?php

class TodoController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->render('index', array(
         'task' => $task,
         ));
     }

     public function actionTask()
     {
         $req = Yii::app()->request;
            if($req->isPostRequest) {
                $this->handlePost($req->getPost('id'), 
                $req->getPost('Task'));
            }
            elseif($req->isPutRequest) {
                $this->handlePut($req->getPut('Task'));

            }
            elseif($req->isDeleteRequest) {
                $this->handleDelete($req->getDelete('id'));
            }
            else {
             $this->handleGet($req->getParam('id'));
            }
     }

     private function handleGet($id)
     {
         if($id) {
             $task = $this->loadModel($id);
             $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         }
         else {
             $data = array();
             $tasks = Task::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'id'));
             foreach($tasks as $task) {
                 $data[] = $task->attributes;
             }
            $this->sendResponse($data);
         }
     }

     private function handlePut($data)
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function handlePost($id, $data)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function saveTask($task, $data)
     {
         if(!is_array($data)){
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, array('No data
                provided.'));
         }
         // $task->setAttributes($data);
         $task->attributes = $data;
         if($task->save()) {
            $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         } else {
            $errors = array();
                foreach($task->errors as $fieldErrors) {
                    foreach($fieldErrors as $error) {
                        $errors[] = $error;
                    }
                }
            $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, $errors);
         }
     }

     private function handleDelete($id)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         if($task->delete()) {
             $this->sendResponse('OK');
         }
         else {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 500, array('Unable to
             delete task.'));
         }
     }

     private function loadModel($id)
     {
         $task = Task::model()->findByPk($id);
         if(!$task) {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 404, array('Task not
             found.'));
         }
         return $task;
     }

     private function sendResponse($data, $responseCode = 200,
    $errors = array())
     {
         $messages = array(
         200 => 'OK',
         400 => 'Bad Request',
         404 => 'Not Found',
         500 => 'Internal Server Error',
         );
         if(in_array($responseCode, array_keys($messages))) {
             header("HTTP/1.0 $responseCode ".$messages[$responseCode],
            true, $responseCode);
         }
         echo json_encode(array(
             'errors' => $errors,
             'data' => $data,
             ));
         Yii::app()->end();
     }
}

?>
```

**view**

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('todo');
    $options = json_encode(array(
    'taskEndpoint' => $this->createUrl('todo/task'),
));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('todo', "todo.
init($options);", CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
<div class="todo-index">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="tasks"></div>
    <div class="new-task">
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm('todo/task')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($task, 'title')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Add')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm()?>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="template-task" type="text/x-dot-template">
    <div class="task{{? it.done==1}} done{{?}}" data-id="{{!it.
id}}">
    <input type="checkbox"{{? it.done==1}}checked {{?}}/>
    <input type="text" value="{{!it.title}}" />
    <a href="#delete" class="delete">Remove</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Can anyone help ?